# Comparison of two well-known bases of the integral homology group of based loop group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, loop-spaces, affine-grassmannian, loop-groups

Let $G$ be a compact simply-connected Lie group. Then one can look at the homology $H_*(\Omega G;\mathbb{Z})$ of the based-loop space $\Omega G$ in at least two different ways:

(1) Via Bott-Samelson's theory. They used Morse theory to show that the Bott-Samelson varieties associated to elements $\omega t_{\lambda}$ of the affine Weyl group lying in the dominant Weyl chamber exhibit an additive basis of $H_*(\Omega G;\mathbb{Z})$.

(Notice the reduced decomposition is obtained by drawing a line segment from the origin to any interior point of the cell represented by $\omega t_{\lambda}$.)

(2) Via affine Grassmannian $Gr_{G_{\mathbb{C}}}$ of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$. It is known that it has the same homotopy type as $\Omega G$ so that 
$$ H_*(\Omega G;\mathbb{Z})\simeq H_*(Gr_{G_{\mathbb{C}}};\mathbb{Z})$$
and that  the latter is generated by the affine Schubert subvarieties.

Is there any way to compare these two bases? Are they identical?